# MATLAB: Generate all possible N x N matrices with specific constraints

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose you have an initial N-by-N matrix, with all diagonal elements equal to zero. You want to generate all possible N-by-N matrices such that:

- all diagonal elements continue to be zero
- columns and rows keep the sum from the initial matrix
- all elements are positive integers (including zero)

For example, for this 3-by-3 initial matrix:

```
0 1 3
2 0 1
3 2 0
```

one possible variation is:

```
0 0 4
3 0 0
2 3 0
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Post some code if you have it.

Comment: Sorry, first post ever on StackOverflow, didn't know I have to post a code. I still don´t have anything but I'll post it as soon as I have something.

Answer (score 1):

An initial idea for an answer, which can certainly be further improved.

You can start thinking of a way to make matrices that have zeros on the diagonal and where rows and columns sum to zeros. If these can be constructed easily, then you can obtain your result by adding your initial matrix with all of them.

e.g.:

```
[ 0  1 -2  1;
  1  0 -1  0;
 -1  2  0 -1;
  0 -3  3  0];
```

You can even restrict these 'helper' matrices to have maximally a single 1 and a single -1 on each row/column. All others can be constructed from them.

e.g.

```
A = [ 0 -1  2 -1;
      2  0 -2  0;
     -2  1  0  1;
      0  0  0  0];
B = [ 0 -1  1  0;
      1  0 -1  0;
     -1  1  0  0;
      0  0  0  0];
C = [ 0  0  1 -1;
      1  0 -1  0;
     -1  0  0  1;
      0  0  0  0];
% A equals B+C
```

I think this at least reduces your problem a bit. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, definitely a new helpful perspective on how to tackle it. I'll get back as soon as I have done some progress.